# Cannot boot into Recovery

Tags: startup, catalina, recovery

What I've done

1. Disable T2 Security Boot
2. In Catalina
3. Add a APFS Volume `mac2`
4. Install Mojave on Volume `mac2` from an external drive
5. (Install security update, copy files and etc.)
6. Remove `Macintosh HD` and its `Data` volume in Mojave

Then when I tried to boot into Recovery, it turns into Internet Recovery (and failed with code -1008F).

Is there a known way to make Recovery work (or reinstall only Recovery), before I try to install Mojave again in-place?

Some info:

```
~ $ diskutil mount Recovery
Volume Recovery on Recovery mounted

~ $ ls /Volumes/Recovery/
C755CEE7-<rest of the UUID>
```

where `C755CEE7...` is the volume UUID of Volume `mac2`.

Comment: If you boot to [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), then the default configuration will display the Recovery volumes to choose from. You can install rEFInd to boot from your internal drive EFI partition or from a flash drive.

Comment: This guy claimed to have done a full disk wipe and install Mojave and also cannot boot into recovery. https://www.v2ex.com/t/634240

Comment: -1008F means that the Macbook is locked in your iCloud. https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dsedvp/error_1008f/

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue, but when I bought the mac at the apple seems it was hardcoded to stay with Catalina and not downgrade to Mojave.

Comment: A newer model does not support old OS. If your model support Mojave, make a installer thumb drive instead of run installer on Catalina. Also you need to disable T2 Security Boot & allow boot from external media.