# Mac with T2 chip, downgraded from Catalina to Mojave, has anyone got a working Recovery?

Tags: catalina, recovery, downgrade, t2

Recovery does not work after downgrade.

- cmd-R goes to Internet Recovery instead of internal Recovery
- Internet Recovery goes error '-1008F'

  - I've disabled Find My Mac and not rolled in the beta program

Initially I thought it was because my special steps to downgrade: [Cannot boot into Recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378267/cannot-boot-into-recovery)

Later I saw a case even a full-wipe-reinstall won't make Recovery work.

Has anyone got a working Recovery, after downgrading from Catalina to Mojave, on a T2 Mac?

Comment: Which exact model of Mac is this?

Comment: @benwiggy 2019 13-inch MacBook Pro. Sure it works with Mojave.

Comment: Is there a Recovery partition? IF not, you may need to create a new one. Here's how you used to do it: I don't know if APFS changes things. http://osxdaily.com/2016/07/03/recreate-recovery-partition-mac/